# Using scenarios for cold obserables in RxJS

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

Obserables in RxJS are cold by default, and they can be converted to hot Obserables if required. I am thinking about the scenarios for using cold Obserables. For hot Obserables, it seems perfect for handling DOM events or system events. What about cold Obserables? Some fellows mentioned like database query or http requests should use cold Obserables, but for me it sounds better to use hot obserables again to share the result.

Any expert could shed some light on using scenarios for cold obserables?

Answer (score 0):

Cold observables are great for database queries etc as it is only executed when you subscribe to the stream. If you were to create a hot observable for a database query, it would be executed straight away, possibly prior to having an subscribers listening to it, so the result could be missed.

There are options where you could reemit the last event whenever a new subscriber attaches to it, but I wouldn't suggest doing that.

Comment: Database query is mentioned very often for using Cold Observables, but I don't think this is a typical scenario because: a) Database query often returns one value which makes applying RX unnecessary; b) It is more often that we want to share the database query result so Connectable Obsevable is more appropriate.